# Internet explorer asks to open or save .php file

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I have several links in a .php page to open other .php files in a div. On clicking a particular link, IE asks to open or save instead of displaying the content in the div. Other links are working fine and displaying the contents normally.

The code for all the links are similar to open in a div.

This works perfect in all other browsers.

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: What is the URL in your browser when IE ask to open/save .php file?

Comment: URL is the index page. These are the modules under that page.

Comment: @TismonVarghese: Which code you want? The php page which contains all the links OR the page which I am trying to open?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Problem was with the header.I had defined header like

```
header('Content-Type: text; charset=utf-8');
```

But after changing it to below header it worked.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Thank you all.